# Monitoring of Azure Hybrid Connections and OnPremise Data Gateway

Tags: azure, azure-hybrid-connections, onpremises-gateway

I'm using the Hybrid Connection Manager and also the On Premise Data Gateway for several projects hosted in the Azure cloud.
There are more and more use cases for those two components and I need to setup a clean monitoring to detect connection troubles (for example when there is a network issue or a reboot of the servers hosting the gateways).

For the HCM, there are Relays metrics I can rely on, but I saw that some of those counters are not reliable. I had issues with my connexion in the past few days, and when I check the ListenerConnections-ClientError or ListenerConnections-ServerError counters, they always equal to 0... this sounds very strange?

Regarding the OnPremise Data Gateway, I think that because it also relies on SBus Relay, I should probably use the same metrics?